# Updating/changing Realm encryption key

Tags: android, realm

I have encrypted `Realm` database in my application. I would like to change the encryption key. Is the proper way to do this making a copy of the `Realm` file with new encryption key or is there some another option available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you have to make a copy of the Realm file with the new encryption key. The method is called `writeEncryptedCopyTo()`: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#writeEncryptedCopyTo-java.io.File-byte:A-

Something like the below should work:

```
RealmConfiguration config1 = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
  .name("old-name")
  .encryptionKey(getOldKey())
  .build()

Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config1);
realm.writeEncryptedCopyTo(new File(context.getFilesDir(), "new-name"), getNewKey());
realm.close();

RealmConfiguration config2 = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
  .name("new-name")
  .encryptionKey(getNewKey())
  .build()
```

Comment: I would like to keep my database name the same, so I write copy to temp file, then delete the original file and then rename tmp file. However Realm uses configuration cache based on path. Is there any way to reset that?

Comment: My bad, wasn't closing the realm instance early enough to get it removed :)